# How to get bounds in WKT or in GeoJson from the selected map range

Tags: google-maps

Trying to get bounds in the google maps selected range area, but sounds like it contains only values like this:

[image]

Not sure how to format it properly to the POLYGON. Please help, can't find the documentation in the google api v3

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: Where did you find map.getBounds() object which can be converted to WKT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope this is useful

you can get the bound in this way  (assume map is the map)

```
    aNord   =   map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();   
    aEst    =   map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
    aSud    =   map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();   
    aOvest  =   map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
```

For the WKT conversion you need only invert lat, lng 
WKT use coord(x,y) google use coord(y,x)

Answer (score 3):

A complete function

```
function getWKTOfGoogleMap() {
    var neLat = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
    var neLng = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
    var swLat = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
    var swLng = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();

    return "POLYGON((" +
            swLng + " " + swLat + "," +
            swLng + " " + neLat + "," +
            neLng + " " + neLat + "," +
            neLng + " " + swLat + "," +
            swLng + " " + swLat +
            "))";
}
```

Comment: any way to get the polygon result from a drawn shape? lat,lng and mRadius?